# Toggling a RadioButton in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a RadioButton with name `radiobutton`. I want to use it as Check Box. But once checked you cannot uncheck it by clicking. So I added this code:

```
radiobutton.Click += (s, e) => 
{        
   if (radiobutton.Checked is false)
       radiobutton.Checked = true;                
   else
       radiobutton.Checked = false;
};
```

However, it does not work. With this code I cannot check the RadioButton. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be an expected result in your case . When we click the RadioButton , the value of Checked will been changed automatically .So if you set it manually again it will be in a endless loop .

By the way ,  **RadioButton** always be used to selected one value between multi options . So the best way to solve the issue is to use  **CheckBox** instead of  **RadioButton** .

If you do want to use the style of **RadioButton** , you could put the RadioButton in a **RadioGroup** . And invoke the method `ClearCheck()` to uncheck the button.

#### in xml

```
<RadioGroup
  android:id="@+id/group"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Check" />
  
</RadioGroup>
```

#### in Activity

```
    bool CurrentStatus = false;

    private void Radio_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radio = FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radio);

        bool isChecked = radio.Checked;


        if (isChecked && CurrentStatus)
        {
            RadioGroup group = FindViewById<RadioGroup>(Resource.Id.group);
            group.ClearCheck();
            CurrentStatus = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentStatus = isChecked;
        }
    }
```

[image]